# how to map an array of objects into an array of Q promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I cannot seem to get my head around this.  I have a list of positions, which I want to turn into an array of promises, which I then want to collect.  It is not working, positionPromises results in an array of nulls (e.g. [ null, null ])

```
var positionPromises  = _.map(positions, function(position) {

    var newPosition = Position({
        'weight': 1
        ,'ideaId': idea.id
    })  

    var promise = null
    Q.all([
                    // asynchronous sets (each does a db lookup)
        newPosition.setDirectionByName(position.direction)
        , newPosition.setSecurityByTicker(position.ticker) 
    ]).then(function(noop) {
        // the position has it's data, invoke save which also returns a promise
        promise = Position.qCreate(newPosition)
    }).done()
    return promise

    console.log("NEVER GET HERE @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
}) // _.map

console.log(positionPromises)
positionPromises.reduce(function(noop, positionPromise){
    console.log('Reduce iteration')
    positionPromise.then(function(position) {
         console.log('THEN')
    })
})
```

### My Solution

From the answers below, this is what I am going with...

the reduce in the above attempt was meant t o be the point where I associate the position back with the idea, prior to returning it to the UI.  BUT  since I am not accumulating anything, ALL works (probably better):

```
var positionPromises = _.map(positions, function(position) {

    var newPosition = Position({
        'weight': 1
        ,'ideaId': idea.id
    })  

    return Q.all([
            newPosition.setDirectionByName(position.direction)
            , newPosition.setSecurityByTicker(position.ticker) 
        ]).then(function(noop) {
            //newPosition.setIdea(idea)
            return Position.qCreate(newPosition)
        })
}) // _.map

Q.all(positionPromises).then(function(positions){
    console.log('RESULTS of POSITION Promises')
    idea.positions = positions

    res.send(idea)

})
```

Comment: What is `Position`, and for what values do its `setXY` methods return promises?

Comment: What is "reduce iteration" meant to do? Your promises will all get executed in parallel, and it hardly makes sense to fold over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var promise = null
> Q.all(…)
> return promise
> ```

You *are* returning `null` here from the function. All assignments to the `promise` variable are done in asynchronous callbacks, which will occur after the mapping function has returned.

What you need to do instead is using `then` for chaining: Compute both `setDirectionByName` and `setSecurityByTicker`, then when both (all) are done `qCreate` a promise, and then yield the value of that promise:

```
var positionPromises  = _.map(positions, function(position) {
    var newPosition = Position({
        'weight': 1,
        'ideaId': idea.id
    });
    return Q.all([
        newPosition.setDirectionByName(position.direction),
        newPosition.setSecurityByTicker(position.ticker) 
    ]).then(function() {
        return Position.qCreate(newPosition);
    });
})
```

Comment: I knew what I was doing was wrong, but figured I would struggle with it instead of asking straight out.  I never thought of returning  Q.all from the map.  Excellent

Comment: Notice that you're not exactly returning `Q.all()`, but the result of calling `.then()` on the result of `Q.all()` - which returns a promise for the result (`Position.qCreate()`) of its callback! (Crazy nesting all this is :-)

Comment: yes  - exactly.  Thank you again - between the nesting and the abstraction it is tricky to keep your head straight.

Answer (score 0):

when you do:

```
...).then(function(noop) {
    // the position has it's data, invoke save which also returns a promise
    promise = Position.qCreate(newPosition)
});
```

it doesn't get called at the time, because it is a async call, so you get nulls array.